# Nested numpy operations

Tags: python, numpy

I have a function like this:

```
def foo(v, w):
    return sum(np.exp(v/w))
```

Where v in the beginning is a numpy array and w a number. Now I want to plot the value of this function for more values of w, so I need a function that works for different sizes of vectors.
My solution for now is the obvious one

```
r = []
for e in w:
    r.append(foo(v, e))
```

but I wonder if there is a better way to do it. Also, I want to stay low on memory, so I need to avoid create a big matrix, then applying the function to every value and sum over the columns (the length of v is more than 5e+4 and the length of w is 1e+3).

Thanks

Comment: Why/How is your solution unsatisfactory.

Comment: I don't know, I just wonder if there exists a way to avoid that for loop. The list can be avoided using another tricks, but I thinks it would be better if I can have a function from R_n x R_m -> R_n in the same function.

Comment: You want to avoid creating a *big* matrix; is 50K x 1K too big?

Comment: Not really, with 4 bytes floats this is around 200MB on memory. The problem is that I don't know how much big will be v, as I said it's more than 5e+4 of size. Not knowing the future value I want to be sure I stay under 1GB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cannot determine an upper bound for the *length* of `v` and ensure that you don't exceed the memory requirements, I think you will have to stay with your solution.

If you can determine an upper bound for *length* of `v` and meet your memory requirements  using a Mx1000 array, you can do this.

```
import numpy as np
v = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
w = np.array([10.,5.])
c = v / w[:, np.newaxis]
d = np.exp(c)
e = d.sum(axis = 1)

>>> 
>>> v
array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
>>> w
array([ 10.,   5.])
>>> c
array([[ 0.1,  0.2,  0.3,  0.4,  0.5],
       [ 0.2,  0.4,  0.6,  0.8,  1. ]])
>>> d
array([[ 1.10517092,  1.22140276,  1.34985881,  1.4918247 ,  1.64872127],
       [ 1.22140276,  1.4918247 ,  1.8221188 ,  2.22554093,  2.71828183]])
>>> e
array([ 6.81697845,  9.47916901])
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks you. I didn't knew I could do `c = v / w[:, np.newaxis]`. Maybe I use your solution but slicing the input data in more fragments.

Comment: If you can get the arrays into the correct shape for [Broadcasting](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html#broadcasting) then you can perform operations and avoid Python ```for``` loop(s).